# What is causing zsh:segmentation fault in this case?

Tags: c++, inheritance, data-structures, polymorphism, rpn

this is my first every time posting a question on stackoverflow so I apologize beforehand If my question seems messy. I have a class named token, and a derived class from it called function, integer, and operator. Token has a public variable of type int called _type. I assigned different _type values for each derived classes. The type for integer is 1, 2 for operator, and 3 for function. The purpose of this is so that I can implement different operations depending on the type encountered. I made an rpn function and in it I have something like this.

```
double RPN::rpn(){
     
    Stack<Token*> rpn_stack;

    while(input_q.empty() == false){

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 1){

            rpn_stack.push(input_q.pop());
        }

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 2){

            double x = rpn_stack.pop()->value();
            double y = rpn_stack.pop()->value();

            //cout << x << y;

            char i = input_q.pop()->op();

            if(i == '*'){

                double result;
                result = x * y;
                rpn_stack.push(new Integer(result));

            }
        }

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 3){

            input_q.pop();
            rpn_stack.push(new Integer(_val));
           
        }
     }
     return rpn_stack.top()->value();
}
```

after testing it a couple of times, I found out that the zsh:segmentation fault problem is caused by the input_q.pop() in

```
        if(input_q.front()->_type == 3){

            input_q.pop();
            rpn_stack.push(new Integer(_val));
           
        }
```

However, the code works if I change the order of the if statements like this

```
double RPN::rpn(){
     
    Stack<Token*> rpn_stack;

    while(input_q.empty() == false){

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 3){

            input_q.pop();
            rpn_stack.push(new Integer(_val));
           
        }

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 1){

            rpn_stack.push(input_q.pop());
        }

        if(input_q.front()->_type == 2){

            double x = rpn_stack.pop()->value();
            double y = rpn_stack.pop()->value();

            //cout << x << y;

            char i = input_q.pop()->op();

            if(i == '*'){

                double result;
                result = x * y;
                rpn_stack.push(new Integer(result));

            }
        }
     }
     return rpn_stack.top()->value();
}
```

which leads me to question whether the problem was input_q.pop() in the first place. It also works if I were to assign input_q.front()->_type to a static variable inside the while loop like this

```
double RPN::rpn(){
     
    Stack<Token*> rpn_stack;

    while(input_q.empty() == false){

        int type = input_q.front()->_type;

        if(type == 1){

            rpn_stack.push(input_q.pop());
        }

        if(type == 2){

            double x = rpn_stack.pop()->value();
            double y = rpn_stack.pop()->value();

            //cout << x << y;

            char i = input_q.pop()->op();

            if(i == '*'){

                double result;
                result = x * y;
                rpn_stack.push(new Integer(result));

            }
        }

        if(type == 3){

            input_q.pop();
            rpn_stack.push(new Integer(_val));
           
        }
       
    }
    return rpn_stack.top()->value();
}
```

At this point I am very confused as to what is causing zsh:segmentation fault when using the first version. Im wondering if the problem lies in accessing input_q.front()->_type? I could just use the second and third version but I really want to know what is causing zsh:segmentation fault on the first version. If it helps, here is the simple program I wrote to test it. I am also using stack and queue if it helps.

```
    Queue<Token *> postfix;
    postfix.push(new Integer(3));
    postfix.push(new Integer(5));
    postfix.push(new Operator("*"));
    RPN rpn(postfix);
    cout << "3 5 *: " << rpn() << endl;
    cout << "-------------" << endl;
    Queue<Token *> postfix2;
    postfix2.push(new Integer(3));
    postfix2.push(new Function("X"));
    postfix2.push(new Operator("*"));
    rpn.set_input(postfix2);
    cout << "3 x *: (x=3): " << rpn(3) << endl;
```

the rpn function is called using the () operator in the RPN class. the RPN class has a private variable called _val that is assigned a value to by the () operator. Hope the information Ive provided is enough. Thank you for your time, would appreciate the input!

Comment: Note: The more we have to change in order to convert the given code into a working example (often necessary to fully understand the problem and test a proposed solution for correctness) the greater the odds that we'll either insert new bugs (and give you wrong answers based on those bugs) or accidentally fix the bug (and give you no answer). All questions should come with a [mre] baked right in. The real beauty of making a MRE as part of the question-asking process is it usually ends the process early because you find the bug yourself. MREs are a groovy debugging tool.

Comment: Side note about polymorphic classes with a type member: They are usually a sign you're headed in a bad direction. Prefer to have an interface of virtual functions that conceal the true nature of the object held from the holder. The code generally scales better and you get fewer surprises.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Ill definitely take that into consideration when asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your first code snippet, when you say this:

```
if(input_q.front()->_type == 1){
    rpn_stack.push(input_q.pop());
}

if(input_q.front()->_type == 2){
...
```

You don't check if there's anything left on the input queue the second time you call `input_q.front`.

A simple fix is to insert a `continue` statement, like this:

```
if(input_q.front()->_type == 1){
    rpn_stack.push(input_q.pop());
    continue;
}

...
```

You will then loop back to the `while` statement which checks whether the queue is empty before proceeding.

There are other places in the code where you need to make a similar change, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I certainly did not think of that. Ill try to implement it. Thank you again for your time.